# Python: URL extender

Tags: python

How can I write a python program that reads a list of short URLs from a text file, extends them, and then dumps them into another file?

I need to find the most recent redirect (returns "200 OK") for each link and have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Start with making a text file with the URLs, make and `openFile()` function that reads the URLs and extends them to your liking and write them into another file. You have to show some effort and code of the things which you have tried. This site is for helping others with their code, not writing it ;-)

Comment: Of course! I am just having trouble getting started because I know so little about python!

Comment: Ok, try writing a function that opens and reads the file, from there on google and stackoverflow are your best friends. Perhaps try some learning on codeacademy to get you started?

Comment: Then start with general Python tutorials. It's easy, when you read through you find pieces that you can use in target application

Comment: Do you mean that you want to dereference the shortened URLs to the full URLs that they refer to?  It's not really clear what you mean by "extend".

Comment: Start with the Requests library

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `requests` module to resolve a URL redirect:

```
import requests

url = '...'
response = requests.head(url)
if response.is_redirect:
    print(response.headers['Location'])
```

Comment: I was looking at examples like this before but they seem to work on a link by link basis. I have to expand 1000 URLs and was wondering if I could somehow make a loop by reading in the URLs from a text file? I know what I want to do, just not how to do it or if it is even a good idea.

Comment: @Blips-n-Chitz I think you need to start with a Python tutorial, which will show you how to write loops.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look for one now!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) library as such:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

fLong = open("longURL.txt", 'w')

with open("shortURL.txt",'r') as fShort:
    for url in fShort:
        br.open(url)
        fLong.write(br.geturl() + '\n')

fLong.close()
```